# separate values of labels in multiple sub columns with python

Tags: python, csv

I have a  CSV dataset like a bellow

```
f1       f2       f3   ...   label1    label2   
float   float    float ...   00010     00001
...                          01000     00010
```

each label column is in binary format. I want to change one column to multiple columns with keeping the heading. each zeros and ones should be separate and placed in separate columns like bellow

```
f1       f2       f3   ...   label1        label2   
float   float    float ...   0,0,0,1,0     0,0,0,0,1
...                          0,1,0,0,0     0,0,0,1,0
```

Could you guide me on how to do this in Python?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very efficeintly with a `pandas dataframe` like this:
(note: there are other methods, like read csv and edit each line).

```py
import pandas as pd

# some test data using strings for their binary equivalents.
example_data = {'f':['a', 'b', 'c'], 'binary_data':['111','101','001']}

df = pd.DataFrame(example_data)

print(df)

def split_parts(row):
    return [x for x in row['binary_data']]


df['split_data']=df.apply(split_parts, axis=1)

print(df)
print(type(df['split_data']))
```

This is the "sample" input:

```
   f  binarydata
0  a         111
1  b         101
2  c         100
```

This is the result:

```
   f binary_data split_data
0  a         111  [1, 1, 1]
1  b         101  [1, 0, 1]
2  c         001  [0, 0, 1]
```

The column `split_data` above is a list of strings each value representing each part of the binary data.

Comment: Thanks... But I mean each value of the label column should be changed to a vector ... each ones and zeros should separate with comma

Comment: @sashiasbshiz i have edited the code so that the split data is now broken down into its parts.

Comment: thanks and do you know how could I save each zero and ones in separate columns?! the heading shouldn't change and it should stay above all of these columns

Comment: yes,  although this is probably best left for a new question in keeping with minimal examples:    https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example   I can say that this would result in a multi colum dataframe (which is more complex).